# Server is can't connecting to any smtp port

Tags: smtp, vps

On my VPS server I'm trying to `smtp` but its not connecting

```
root@server1:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying port_number...
Trying port_number...
Trying ipv4_address...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested 
    address
```

After some time its returning error.

But when I'm trying to ping on `smtp.gmail.com` its working

```
    root@server1:~# ping smtp.gmail.com
    PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (64.233.168.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=7.45 ms
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=7.43 ms
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=7.43 ms
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=4 ttl=44 time=7.41 ms
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=5 ttl=44 time=7.41 ms
    64 bytes from oj-in-f108.1e100.net (port): icmp_seq=6 ttl=44 time=7.45 ms
```

What I am missing in my server configuration?

Comment: Which hosting provider do you use? Google Cloud?

Comment: could be something related to firewalls

Comment: Extend your question with an `iptables-save` output.

Answer (score 2):

This error means telnet cannot open local (!!!) port for connecting to the gmail tcp port.

Please check if this sas something useful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640619/cannot-assign-requested-address-possible-causes

If telnet to http or anything else doesn't work either then the problem may be your kernel / sysctl configuration and nothing to do with gmail or smtp.